# Tools to install Linux inside Windows?

Tags: windows, linux

What tools can I use to install a Linux distro inside Windows and run both at the same time? I already Googled this and I did not find what I needed.

Comment: Do you want to have a Linux distribution, this would mean that you need some sort of virtual machine, or do you want to use Linux "type" commands. In the later case you can have a look at Cygwin, you have here that you can have Linux type shell windows but you can also use the commands inside Windows (when adding the right directory to your path)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a virtual machine program like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), then create a virtual machine and install Linux to it.

You will get a more immersive Linux experience, but it will be slower than running Linux directly:

[image: screenshot courtesy https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/wiki/Screenshots/Ubuntu_14.04_on_Windows_7.png]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft's [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about):

> The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run GNU/Linux environment -- including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a virtual machine.
>
> You can:
>
> 1. Choose your favorite GNU/Linux distributions from the Windows Store.
> 2. Run common command-line free software such as grep, sed, awk, or other ELF-64 binaries.
> 3. Run Bash shell scripts and GNU/Linux command-line applications including:
>
>    - Tools: vim, emacs, tmux
>    - Languages: Javascript/node.js, Ruby, Python, C/C++, C# & F#, Rust, Go, etc.
>    - Services: sshd, MySQL, Apache, lighttpd
> 4. Install additional software using own GNU/Linux distribution package manager.
> 5. Invoke Windows applications using a Unix-like command-line shell.
> 6. Invoke GNU/Linux applications on Windows.

It appears especially suited for BASH:

[image: Image courtesy https://www.anandtech.com/show/11401/microsoft-build-2017-recap-expecting-windows/5]